# Postgres detach a primary key from a sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

how can i detach a primary key of table from a sequence with out having to drop the table

Comment: Programmatically, or with an admin utility?

Answer (score 5):

With "detach" you mean probably, removing the default for the column to the next value of the sequence. 
For example, say you have a table definition like this:

```
 Column   |  Type   |                           Modifiers                            
------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 yourcolumn | integer | not null default nextval('yourtable_yourcolumn_seq'::regclass)
```

you want to remove this part: `default nextval('yourtable_yourcolumn_seq'::regclass)`

If so, you can do it with this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ALTER COLUMN yourcolumn DROP DEFAULT;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for, an ALTER query.